# MySQL relevance search based on number of words in the field

Tags: php, mysql

```
1 MySQL
2 PHP and MySQL
3 PHP MySQL Database Search
```

These are three rows in my table. On applying search for keywords 'php mysql database' it should show result in order of 3-2-1 starting from row 3 as there are all 3 keywords in it.

I tried this code but it is only showing all three results but not in order that I want.

```
SELECT data,
MATCH(data) AGAINST('PHP MySQL Database' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(data) AGAINST('PHP MySQL Database' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

comparing [the docs for boolean mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) and [natural language mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> **Boolean:** Boolean full-text searches have these characteristics:
>    They do not automatically sort rows in order of decreasing relevance.
>
> **Natural Language:** When MATCH() is used in a WHERE clause, as in the example shown earlier, the rows returned are automatically sorted with the highest relevance first.

So my suggestion is to use natural language mode and simply leave out your explicit ordering clauses.

## note on default settings

Quoting the above-linked documentation:

> Some words are ignored in full-text searches:
>
> Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of words that are found by full-text searches is four characters.
>
> The default minimum word length and stopword list can be changed as described in Section [12.9.6, “Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)”.

And from the page which that links to:

> For example, if you want three-character words to be searchable, you can set the ft_min_word_len variable by putting the following lines in an option file:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

Comment: getting this error.  **Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list**

Comment: Okay, that may hint at your initial problem, you don't have a FULLTEXT index on the column you are searching; `ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT(data);`

Comment: Thanks for your help this code is working just fine. I am using this code            SELECT data, MATCH (data) AGAINST ('php mysql database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score FROM table WHERE MATCH (data) AGAINST ('php mysql database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);

Comment: But there is another problem with this code it is not working for words having 3 or less letters (eg 'php').It is returning empty set.
SELECT data FROM table
    WHERE MATCH (data)
    AGAINST ('php' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);

Comment: I added an edit leading you to how to tune your settings, if you consider all the implications and still want to...